# Update Table Set From is not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am facing a strange problem with SSMS 2012 this noon as I have below table:

```
Serial_num       Item_NBR      SeqNo      Parent_SeqNo     Depth     Parent_Item_NBR
AAA              123221          1            NULL           1           
AAA              112333          2              1            2        
AAA              223345          3              2            2
AAA              122322          4              3            3
```

And I am running below query to update table with parent_item_NBR:

```
 UPDATE tbl SET PARENT_ITEM_NBR = (  SELECT top 1 a.ITEM_NUM
 FROM tbl b where
 a.SERIAL_NUM = b.SERIAL_NUM and a.SEQNO=b.PARENT_SEQNO and a.DEPTH=b.DEPTH-1
 ) FROM tbl a
```

But its giving me below results :

```
Serial_num       Item_NBR      SeqNo      Parent_SeqNo     Depth     Parent_Item_NBR
AAA              123221          1            NULL           1         123221
AAA              112333          2              1            2         112333          
AAA              223345          3              2            2         223345
AAA              122322          4              3            3         NULL
```

Instead I need

```
   Serial_num       Item_NBR      SeqNo      Parent_SeqNo     Depth     Parent_Item_NBR
AAA              123221          1            NULL           1         123221
AAA              112333          2              1            2         123221
AAA              223345          3              2            2         112333
AAA              122322          4              3            3         223345
```

Please suggest if there is any work around for utilizing self-joins to update the table.
Thanks.

Comment: Your update query is not very clear to me what you are trying to do. Of course, the results you are seeing today are not even guaranteed to work in the future (you have top 1 but no order by). Of course maybe the top 1 is redundant based on the join if your data does not allow multiple values for depth. Can you put together something to help clarify your question. sqlfiddle.com would be a great place to start.

Comment: Try changing "UPDATE tbl" to "UPDATE a"  (in other words, update the alias)

Comment: @SeanLange I was messing with two level nesting to get the parent_Item_nbr, only level nesting was required. Please see radar's answer. That Worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do `self join` in the update statement

The depth condition is not needed , with depth condition, 3rd row parent item nbr would be of 1st row as 
2-1 = 1

Try this.

```
update p
set Parent_Item_NBR = p1.item_nbr
from project p
join project p1
on p.serial_num = p1.serial_num
and isnull(p.parent_seqno,1) = p1.seqno
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH CTE AS 
 (
   SELECT A.PARENT_ITEM_NBR
         ,C.TOP_ITEM_NUM 
   FROM tbl A 
         CROSS APPLY ( SELECT top 1 a.ITEM_NUM
                       FROM tbl b 
                      where a.SERIAL_NUM = b.SERIAL_NUM 
                        and a.SEQNO =  b.PARENT_SEQNO 
                        and a.DEPTH = b.DEPTH-1
                     ) C(TOP_ITEM_NUM)
 )
UPDATE CTE 
 SET PARENT_ITEM_NBR = TOP_ITEM_NUM
```